# How to plot an animation from data in matrix format

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, graphics, gnuplot

I have a text file with a series of matrices, in this format

```
1000
0000
0000
0000

0000
0100
0000
0000

0000
0000
0010
0000

0000
0000
0000
0001
```

This file is the result of an simulation generated by a Fortran program (the real matrices are in 20x20 format). I need build a graph of this matrices in sequence, a animation. Example, in the sequence above the expected result is a pixel moving diagonally (with "1" as a pixel)

I can (in python) generate a bmp file of one matrix

```
from PIL import Image

m1=([[1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0]])

img = Image.new('1', (4, 4))
pixels = img.load()

for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixels[i, j] = m1[j][i]

img.save('/home/marco/Pictures/image1.bmp')
```

with several bmp files I can make an animated gif, Ok. The problem is that I have 2000 matrices, so by hand is a tedious work, not elegant

Any idea please? Perhaps in Python, Matplotlib, R, Gnuplot. 
I think that directly in Fortran I will have more work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R, one could do:

```
txt <- readLines(n=19)
1000
0000
0000
0000

0000
0100
0000
0000

0000
0000
0010
0000

0000
0000
0000
0001
# install.packages("animation") # uncomment and run, if needed
library(animation)
saveGIF({
  par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  lapply(split(txt, cumsum(txt=="")), function(x) {
    x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x, ""), as.integer))
    plot(as.raster(xor(x, 255)), interpolate = FALSE)
  })
}, interval = 0.3)
```

[image]